# Why are the components not rerendering after Response?

Tags: spring, axios, vuejs3

***Table with pinia store equipmentlist, fethced from usequipments but table does not rerender
**VueTableComponent*****

```
  <script setup lang="ts">
import { useEquipmentStore } from '~/store/equipmentStore'
import useEquipments from '~/composables/equipments'

const { getEquipmentList } = useEquipments()
onBeforeMount(() => { getEquipmentList() })

const state = useEquipmentStore()
const equipmentList: any = state.equipmentList
const loaded = state.loaded
</script>

<template>
  <el-table :key="loaded" :data="equipmentList" style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column type="expand">
      <template #default="props">
        ID: {{ props.row.id }}
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column label="ID" prop="id" />
    <el-table-column label="Name" prop="name" />
  </el-table>
</template>
```

**Typescript File for all CRUD Operations equipment.ts**

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import http from '../http-common'
import { useEquipmentStore } from '~/store/equipmentStore'

export default function useEquipments() {
  const state = useEquipmentStore()
  const errors = ref([]) // array of strings
  const router = useRouter()
  const getEquipmentList = async() => {
    try {
      console.log(state.equipmentList.length)
      const response = await http.get('/equipment/list')
      state.equipmentList = response.data
      console.log(state.equipmentList.length)
      console.log(state.equipmentList[0])
    }
    catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
```

**Equipment(Pinia)Store**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import type { Ref } from 'vue'

export const useEquipmentStore = defineStore('equipment', {
  state: () => ({
    equipment: ref({}) as any,
    equipmentList: ref([]) as Ref<any[]>,
  }),
  actions: {
    reset() {
      this.equipment = {}
      this.equipmentList = []
    },
  },
})
```

[1. i called several times getEquipment list and it is faster done then i stored an initial equipment, 2. i clicked on the link on the left and fetched several times more and as u can see there is something fetchd but not displayed, 3. after repeating to home and again to Link the component is there and alll other next fetches do indeed function well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvGKH.png)

**Main.ts**

```
  app.component('InputText', InputText)
    app.mount('#app')
    useEquipments().initDB()
  }
```

**same fetching class equipment.ts**

```
  const initDB = () => {
    try {
      if (state.equipmentList.length === 0) { storeEquipment({ id: 1, name: 'Firma' }) }
      else {
        for (const equipment of state.equipmentList) {
          console.log(equipment)
          if (equipment === 'Firma')
            state.equipmentList.splice(state.equipmentList.indexOf(equipment), 1)
        }
      }
    }
    catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
```

Comment: i think i solved id

Comment: i was setting state.equipmentList always to response but somehow i added an if statement to the getEquipmentlist fetch -> if(respnse.data.length > 0) -> state.eqList = respnse.data